# Vector loops throwing 2 errors?

Tags: c++, vector, mean

lab26.cpp: In function ‘int meanUsingIterators(const std::vector&)’:
lab26.cpp:35:13: error: no match for ‘operator/’ (operand types are ‘double’ and ‘std::vector::const_iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >}’)

mean = sum / end;

lab26.cpp: In function ‘int meanUsingPointers(const std::vector&)’:
lab26.cpp:51:13: error: invalid operands of types ‘double’ and ‘std::vector::const_pointer {aka const int*}’ to binary ‘operator/’ .

mean = sum / end;

===========================================================================

```
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int meanUsingIndexing(const vector<int>& v)   
{

    vector<int>::size_type i, end = v.size();
    double sum = 0;
    double mean;

    for(i = 0; i < end; i++)
    {
        sum += v.at(i); // or sum += v[i]
    }
    mean = sum / end;
    return round(mean);
}

int meanUsingIterators(const vector<int>& v)  
{

    vector<int>::const_iterator i, end = v.cend();
    double sum = 0;
    double mean;

    for(i = v.cbegin(); i < end; i++)      
    {
        sum += *i;
    }
    mean = sum / end;
    return round(mean);
}

int meanUsingPointers(const vector<int>& v)    
{

    vector<int>::const_pointer i, end = v.data() + v.size();
    double sum = 0;
    double mean;

    for(i = v.data(); i < end; i++)
    {
        sum += *i;
    }
    mean = sum / end;
    return round(mean);
}
```

Comment: You are trying to divide by an iterator or a pointer. That's also what the error says. But what you really want to do is not divide by the _memory location_ of the last element (or similar) but just the number of elements.

Comment: By declaring `end = v.size()` by comma separation from where you declare `i`, you are declaring it as an iterator where you should be declaring on a separate line as an integer.

Comment: @DetectivePikachu No, that line is already declaring integers. You're looking at the wrong function :P

Comment: None of the lines declaring `end` are declaring integers, what in the world are you on about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `no match for ‘operator/’ (operand types are ‘double’ and ‘std::vector::const_iterator`.

So, a `double` and an iterator with a division sign between them is what's causing that.

When `end = v.cend();` you can't use `end` as the number of elements (to get the mean). Replace `mean = sum / end;` with `mean = sum / v.size();`

> `invalid operands of types ‘double’ and ‘std::vector::const_pointer`.

Here it's a `double` and a `const*` with a division sign between them that is the problem.

When `end = v.data() + v.size();` you can't use `end` as the number of elements (to get the mean). Replace `mean = sum / end;` with `mean = sum / v.size();`

Comment: Such a dumb mistake. Thank you very much! I spent more time than I should have on this.

Comment: @JamesMcMillan You are welcome! It's not rare that one makes mistakes and get stuck. 30 minutes on the couch tends to solve it for me :-)

Comment: I'll definitely take that into consideration! I love to code but man does this data structures class get on my nerves lol!